# how to regex by \r\n in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the text looks like this:

```
1
00:00:01,860 --> 00:00:31,210
Affil of fifth at fat at all the social ball and said, with all this little in the

2
00:00:31,210 --> 00:01:03,060
mid limited and will cost a lot, for want of a lot of it is I never do this or below are the innocent of fat in the annual own none will bit less often were a little the earth the oven for the area of some of them some of the atom in the long will recall the law, will cost you the ball a little less of Odessa and coal rule the Vikings in at a loss

3
00:01:03,980 --> 00:01:33,150
of our lady of one of the will of the wall routing visiting little sign of the limited use of a lot of wind up with a loss of 14 and uncivil will find a site to lop off call them into solid, a London, can we stop go to work as a gay sailor kissing a lot of that scene of the law that on them in this case

4
00:01:33,950 --> 00:02:03,190
will almost a kind wilkinson's, and that a settlement, or the fog collared of the unknown, some would call and all of this was a little, some of us up a lot of letters, union would quit them or not will be or will lend money to zoning and will open the door to that of the novel opens in

5
00:02:04,240 --> 00:02:24,180
it and solidity can cut later with boats can die to only see not open only to six and 0:50 and world go back a at the fat of that at that
```

I would like to extract ONLY the sentences from the text.  such as
"Affil of fifth at fat at all the social ball and said, with all this little in the mid limited and will cost a lot, for want of a ...."

so the raw text is look like this:

```
  "1\r\n00:00:01,860 --> 00:00:31,210\r\nAffil of fifth at fat at all the social ball and said, with all this little in the\r\n\r\n2\r\n00:00:31,210 --> 00:01:03,060\r\nmid limited and will cost a lot, for want of a lot of it is I never do this or below are the innocent of fat in the annual own none will bit less often were a little the earth the oven for the area of some of them some of the atom in the long will recall the law, will cost you the ball a little less of Odessa and coal rule the Vikings in at a loss\r\n\r\n3\r\n00:01:03,980 --> 00:01:33,150\r\nof our lady of one of the will of the wall routing visiting little sign of the limited use of a lot of wind up with a loss of 14 and uncivil will find a site to lop off call them into solid, a London, can we stop go to work as a gay sailor kissing a lot of that scene of the law that on them in this case\r\n\r\n4\r\n00:01:33,950 --> 00:02:03,190\r\nwill almost a kind wilkinson's, and that a settlement, or the fog collared of the unknown, some would call and all of this was a little, some of us up a lot of letters, union would quit them or not will be or will lend money to zoning and will open the door to that of the novel opens in\r\n\r\n5\r\n00:02:04,240 --> 00:02:24,180\r\nit and solidity can cut later with boats can die to only see not open only to six and 0:50 and world go back a at the fat of that at that\r\n\r\n"
```

by checking the raw text, we might   separate  the text by "\r\n" something like this but I do not know how to write the regex.

Comment: `text.split('\n').strip()`?

Comment: Actually, `text.splitlines()[2::4]` looks more like it.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply get every fourth line, starting from the third? Then you can join on a space.

```
text = '''1
00:00:01,860 --> 00:00:31,210
Affil of fifth at fat at all the social ball and said, with all this little in the

2
00:00:31,210 --> 00:01:03,060
mid limited and will cost a lot, for want of a lot of it is I never do this or below are the innocent of fat in the annual own none will bit less often were a little the earth the oven for the area of some of them some of the atom in the long will recall the law, will cost you the ball a little less of Odessa and coal rule the Vikings in at a loss

3
00:01:03,980 --> 00:01:33,150
of our lady of one of the will of the wall routing visiting little sign of the limited use of a lot of wind up with a loss of 14 and uncivil will find a site to lop off call them into solid, a London, can we stop go to work as a gay sailor kissing a lot of that scene of the law that on them in this case

4
00:01:33,950 --> 00:02:03,190
will almost a kind wilkinson's, and that a settlement, or the fog collared of the unknown, some would call and all of this was a little, some of us up a lot of letters, union would quit them or not will be or will lend money to zoning and will open the door to that of the novel opens in

5
00:02:04,240 --> 00:02:24,180
it and solidity can cut later with boats can die to only see not open only to six and 0:50 and world go back a at the fat of that at that'''
t = ' '.join(text.splitlines()[2::4])
```

Result:

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> for line in textwrap.wrap(t, width=50):
...     print(line)
...
Affil of fifth at fat at all the social ball and
said, with all this little in the mid limited and
will cost a lot, for want of a lot of it is I
never do this or below are the innocent of fat in
the annual own none will bit less often were a
little the earth the oven for the area of some of
them some of the atom in the long will recall the
law, will cost you the ball a little less of
Odessa and coal rule the Vikings in at a loss of
our lady of one of the will of the wall routing
visiting little sign of the limited use of a lot
of wind up with a loss of 14 and uncivil will find
a site to lop off call them into solid, a London,
can we stop go to work as a gay sailor kissing a
lot of that scene of the law that on them in this
case will almost a kind wilkinson's, and that a
settlement, or the fog collared of the unknown,
some would call and all of this was a little, some
of us up a lot of letters, union would quit them
or not will be or will lend money to zoning and
will open the door to that of the novel opens in
it and solidity can cut later with boats can die
to only see not open only to six and 0:50 and
world go back a at the fat of that at that
```

Comment: @vks - And what exactly makes you think that this text is human-generated? It's a subtitle file, which is almost guaranteed to be automatically generated via OCR.

Comment: Can I ask you one question? like how to separate the text such as sentence by sentence. since the transcript does not really have the punctuation.

Comment: @dd90p just dont do `join`

Comment: @dd90p - The original before the `' '.join()` has each individual line, but there's no way to recover actual sentence structure if those data are absent.

Answer (score 4):

```
(?<=[\r\n])[a-zA-Z].*
```

You can use `re.findall` with this regex.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/QIwQ9z/1

To make this more error free, use

```
(?:\d+:){2}\d+,\d+ --> (?:\d+:){2}\d+,\d+[\r\n]+([^\n]+)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/QIwQ9z/2

Comment: Regex is not necessary here at all.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 not necessary accompanied by a downvote? i find this much more stable than urs

Comment: This particular expression is also quite fragile, as it will break if a relevant line starts with a number.

Comment: Improve it all you like; it'll still be a fragile hack for the Y in an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In its current form, it's so fragile I would almost _expect_ it to break... but silently, simply dropping a relevant line that doesn't start with one of the hard-coded characters. It's simply the wrong approach.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 sry but i would use it anyday against ur solution.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Results from this solution are almost guaranteed to be broken, while results from my solution are not. It's like parsing HTML with regex - messy and easily broken, because it's inherently wrong.

Comment: Also, if you want an easy example of a word that starts with a number, how about... a number? Any number. Years, populations, anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131120/discussion-between-tigerhawkt3-and-vks).